# Smart Switch Compatibility

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

I’m looking at purchasing some smart switches to replace my normal switches. But before I do I wanted to ensure they would be compatible with what I’m looking at. Below is the image of the wiring for the new smart switch and the other is how my wiring currently looks at home. It appears I’m missing one wire. Will I still be able to use it without one of them? I’m not too familiar with wiring but I believe it’s missing the neutral wire...

[image: Smart Switch]

[image: My Switch]

Comment: Whoa. The metal box always needs to be grounded FIRST.  (and only, in the case of a switch; switches pick up ground via the mounting screws).  So attach that loose ground wire to a grounding screw in the back of the box.  If no screw is present, there will be a hole tapped 10-32; use that; the hardware store sells little green #10-32 screws.

Comment: Sorry, I just pulled the ground wire out for the picture, it was grounded before. Haha, thanks.

Comment: @Zach -- what make and model is the smart switch that you're trying to put in even?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel this one: Limited-time deal: meross https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07KXNHNCB/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_i_N9QE15SETP27NNT1N1KN

Comment: @Zach -- is pulling new wire (and probably going to a different smartswitch) an option?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I thought about it, but the other issue is that all switches in my house don’t have a neutral wire. It would be costly to rewire them all as I want to replace almost all my switches with smart switches. My house’s wiring seems to have been replaced within the last ten years, but it was either done by the owner or a really cheap electrician sadly..

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR Switch Loop, No Neutral

You have a **switch loop**. With a switch loop, power goes from panel to fixture to switch, instead of panel to switch to fixture. That is perfectly safe, but the problem is that you end up with no **neutral** at the switch. A neutral is simply unnecessary with an ordinary switch. But a neutral is required for many (not all) smart switches, timers, motion detectors, WiFi switches, etc. Current code requires a neutral (or an easily added neutral in conduit) at most switch boxes. But older houses (like yours and mine) have plenty of switch loops.

White is *usually* neutral. But in the case of a switch loop *using standard /2 cable*, white is permitted to be used as hot or switched hot. Actually, it is supposed to be hot, not switched hot, but that is irrelevant to this discussion. Since your switch has black and white wires connected, it *must* (unless there was some major code violation going on) be a switch loop. If it was not a switch loop then it would have two non-white wires (typically both black, but not always).

End result: You will either need to run a new cable **or** find a smart switch that specifically does **not** require neutral. A smart switch needs power. Short version: it can get power from battery (needs changing), capacitors (very limited), leak through hot (works great with incandescent bulbs but not with most LEDs), neutral (ideal, except when you don't have neutral at the switch!) or ground. You can't simply use ground as neutral - it will *probably function* but it will not be code-compliant and is therefore not a good idea. There are some switches actually designed and listed to use ground for power, but the amount of power is limited and this capability varies by brand - and by model within each brand.

Comment: So technically I could jump the neutral to the hot wire? I saw a comment somewhere for this brand that said it actually comes with a jump wire. Do that seem right?

Comment: No! Jumper neutral to hot is a short circuit. Jumper neutral to ground is *possible* but **only if certified/listed for that usage**.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that’s what I meant. I’ve sent an email to the manufacturer to find out. Thanks!